# Bootstrap not responsive on iOS

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Bootstrap 3 for my website and I can't figure why it's not responsive on iOS (shows like the desktop view). I have already do a quick search about this problem and yes I use the template code provided by Bootstrap but it still doesn't seem to work. Here is the beginning of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laurent Doucet — Graphic designer</title>
    <meta name="description" content="—">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is my website: http://www.laurentdoucet.be

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Show us the parts of the code that you wrote specifically for mobile and explain what specifically is not working about it

Comment: @takendarkk

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

It should be responsive with this line of code but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Probably because your site is in a frame.. http://www.bepxlagency.be/laurentdoucet/ looks fine

Comment: @takendarkk

Code is to long, please go on my website and inspect the code. As you will see I use the grid system.

Comment: `<div class="col-xs-12">` This means be 12 columns on all devices and all sizes. How did you want this to change between desktop/mobile?

Comment: @ZimSystem So it's all about the redirection system of my host name? Do you know how to fix this? 

My website is hosted on bepxlagency.be/laurentdoucet but I use (and want to use) the name laurendoucet.be as main address.

Comment: @Laurent are you using a frame redirect to point one domain at another? You really shouldn't do that. It is a terrible hack. You should set up your domain correctly so that the A records point to your hosting server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of frames is preventing your viewport tag from working.

You need to include a viewport meta tag in the outer page also:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>www.laurentdoucet.be</title>
  </head>
  <frameset>
    <frame src="http://www.bepxlagency.be/laurentdoucet/" name="redir">
    <noframes>
      <p>Original location:
        <a href="http://www.bepxlagency.be/laurentdoucet/">http://www.bepxlagency.be/laurentdoucet/</a>
      </p>
    </noframes>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry to ask this "stupid" question but I don't understand where I should put this code?

Comment: This is the code of your webpage. All I have added is the meta tag.

Comment: Unless you have set up a domain mask and this page was created for you by the domain registrar? Is this the case?

Comment: I use the domain and space I have on bepxlagency.be (at one.com) but I have my own domain name laurentdoucet.be (at gandi.net) which redirect to the space on bepxlagency.be
What should I do? is this possible to display "laurentdoucet.be" and use the space on bexlagency.be?

By the way thanks a lot

Comment: Domain management can be complex and varies between providers. I would suggest that you contact one.com and tell them that you **wish to use an external domain wth your hosting account**. They should be able to tell you how to configure your one.com and gandhi.net accounts.